# Reusing methods in AngularJS instead of defining multiple variables

Tags: angularjs, optimization, methods, angularjs-scope, repeat

I've created a sample application in angularjs.
I've different variables(colorNew and numberNew) which hold the value of similar operation. 
How can I optimize the code(create a method), so that I can reuse my angular.forEach as well as split method shown in the code instead of writing them multiple times?

Here's the code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.myData = [
   { 
     'car': 'Ford',
     'color': 'Black, White, Blue',
     'number': '1, 2, 3',
     'model': 'Figo'     
   }, { 
     'car': 'Ford',
     'color': 'Red, Black, Silver',
     'number': '4,5',
     'model': 'Endeavour'     
   },{ 
     'car': 'Jaguar',
     'color': 'White',
     'number': '6',
     'model': 'F-Type'     
   },
    ];
  
    $scope.getData = function(){
   $scope.color = this.car.color.split(',');
   $scope.number = this.car.number.split(',');
   console.log($scope.color);
   $scope.colorNew = angular.forEach($scope.color, function() {
  return $(this);
   }).join(' | ');
   $scope.numberNew = angular.forEach($scope.number, function() {
  return $(this);
   }).join(' | ');
   console.log($scope.colorNew);
   console.log($scope.numberNew);
    };
}]);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="createData">Create Data</button>
  <div class="container">
 <div ng-repeat="car in myData" class="parent">
   <div>
  <label>Car:</label>
  <span>{{car.car}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
      <div>
  <label>Model:</label>
  <span>{{car.model}}</span>
   </div>
   <br />
   <button ng-click="getData(obj)">Click Me!</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you define `color` and `number` as `string` instead `string-array`, ex: `['one','two']`?

Comment: You're right! But in my actual application I get them as strings from the backend JSON.